# Generate error message when "async void" is used in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await, msbuild

There are a lot of Question and Answer about the `async void` theme. And we all agree this is not a good thing, and I believe in all cases is avoidable. That Is why I want to create a Visual Studio Error Message when it is used.

In other cases it was success, like: When a function returns with `Task` the visual studio makes a warning [CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014). And we configured the handle to this warning as error with  [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) mechanism.  Here is the code of it:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WarningsAsErrors>CS4014</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see the [CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014) as handled like an error. It is works fine. But for `async void` there is no warning message, that is why we cannot configure to handle this as an error.

**Is there any way to add custom error/warning messages to `msbuild` build process?**

To create own error/warning messages will be very helpful in lot of cases.

Comment: There's one use case for `async void` though and that's event handlers.

Comment: With a wrapper function you can also able to handle this case

Comment: You could write an analyzer to detect async void and then generate your own errors/warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to add custom error/warning messages to msbuild build
> process?

There is a VS extension called [AsyncFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer) that can detect async void methods.

However, it just turns these async void methods as warnings rather than errors. And it seems that `WarningsAsErrors` xml mode does not work for it.

**So** if you still want to treat them as errors, I suggest you could create a new configuration called `Production` in VS IDE and then add them in `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Production|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In this **Configuration**, it will treat every warnings as errors and it is easy for you to find each async void methods. (This is a better function which l have tested for your issue). After it, you can change Configuration back to any other else to build your project. It will

More about this function, you can refer to [this related case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285079/treating-warnings-as-errors-in-visual-studio-2019-for-build-but-not-intellisense/60301367#60301367).

**In addition**, if it still does not satisfy you, you should [create an analyzer to detect Async Methods](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/an-analyzer-that-checks-your-async-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned [AsyncFixer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer) and [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncFixer) are super useful when dealing with async code. They both package a Roslyn analyzer that detects many async issues and provides an automatic fix for them as well in most cases.

Using the `.editorconfig` in Visual Studio you can configure specific warnings as errors:

```
[*.cs]

# AsyncFixer03: Fire-and-forget async-void methods or delegates
dotnet_diagnostic.AsyncFixer03.severity = error
```

And you can set that straight from the Solution Explorer in case you've added AsyncFixer as a nuget package:

[image]

By adding the extension as a nuget package, it also automatically works on any CI server that builds your code without any further installation.